# In python Django I want to run two statements on if else that is if email is taken show it or if username is taken show it

Tags: python, django

I have a html registration page where I am displaying if any username or email exists or not so if it exists then display username is taken and if email exists it will display email is taken but the problem is even if I give email in the email field in the html form it says username is taken but not email I tried elif statement it didn't worked the username is taken is working perfectly but not email. I mean both statements should run individually

If anyone knows please help

This is my views.py

```
def Register(request):
    try:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            username = request.POST.get('username')
            email = request.POST.get('email')
            password = request.POST.get('password')

        try:
            if User.objects.filter(username = username).first():
                messages.success(request, 'Username is taken.')
                return redirect('/register/')

            if User.objects.filter(email = email).first():
                messages.success(request, 'Email is taken.')
                return redirect('/register/')
            
            user_obj = User(username = username , email = email)
            user_obj.set_password(password)
            user_obj.save()
    
            profile_obj = Profile.objects.create(user = user_obj )
            profile_obj.save()
            return redirect('/login/')

        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

    except Exception as e:
            print(e)

    return render(request , 'register.html')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if User.objects.filter(username=username).exists() or User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
    error_message = ''
    email_error = ('', 'Email is taken. ')[User.objects.filter(email=email).exists()]
    username_error = ('', 'Username is taken. ')[User.objects.filter(username=username).exists()]
    error_message = email_error + username_error
    messages.success(request, error_message)
    return redirect('/register/')
```

When the username is already used, the first if condition will complete the function due to the return value and it will not enter the email check. To avoid this, we can specify them in a single if condition. I have put the full code below.

````
    try:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            username = request.POST.get('username')
            email = request.POST.get('email')
            password = request.POST.get('password')

        try:
            if User.objects.filter(username=username).exists() or User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
                error_message = ''
                email_error = ('', 'Email is taken. ')[User.objects.filter(email=email).exists()]
                username_error = ('', 'Username is taken. ')[User.objects.filter(username=username).exists()]
                error_message = email_error + username_error
                messages.success(request, error_message)
                return redirect('/register/')

            user_obj = User(username = username , email = email)
            user_obj.set_password(password)
            user_obj.save()
    
            profile_obj = Profile.objects.create(user = user_obj )
            profile_obj.save()
            return redirect('/login/')

        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

    except Exception as e:
            print(e)

    return render(request , 'register.html')```
````

Comment: Yes this is right but I have put the code its not working saying local variable 'username' referenced before assignment

Comment: this is the message I am getting tuple indices must be integers or slices, not NoneType

Comment: getting this error too tuple indices must be integers or slices, not User

Comment: Can you tell me on which line or where it got the error? @JamesRowling

Comment: I am seeing this error on the terminal its saying "tuple indices must be integers or slices, not User ", "tuple indices must be integers or slices, not NoneType" also no message is displayed  and exists function is not working I have used first over there when I tried to put the registered email may be these lines causing error  email_error = ('', 'Email is taken. ')[User.objects.filter(email=email).exists()]
    username_error = ('', 'Username is taken. ')[User.objects.filter(username=username).exists()]

Comment: I think it is due to the difference of Python versions. Would you try these two lines? If these give an error, we will have to write long if conditions. You can also use ```first()``` instead of ```exists()``` if you wish.


New lines : 
```username_error = 'Username is taken. ' if User.objects.filter(username=username).exists() else '' 


email_error = 'Email is taken. ' if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists() else '' 
```

Comment: i am using python 3.9.4 version

Comment: its giving syntax error can you write these lines in order

Comment: first line: ```username_error = 'Username is taken. ' if User.objects.filter(username=username).exists() else ''```
second line: ```email_error = 'Email is taken. ' if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists() else ''```